# Foreground job for react native [IOS]

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

Thanks for reading this, Im pretty new to mobile development. I was just wondering whether is there something like *react-native-background-timer* but only runs on foreground. As i read that this module also runs in background

What i want is a foreground task that runs every 60 seconds to perform a fetch() and when the app is closed it won't run it. Until they open then app again then it continues.

Any help would be much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way where i detect the state changes when the users closes the app or opens it

```
_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
if (this.state.appState === 'background' && nextAppState === 'active') {
  //start timer
} else if (nextAppState === 'background') {
  //end timer
}
this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });}
```

Just wondering whether is there a better way of doing it?